# Convert Cxx Vector into Julia Vector

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, julia

```
julia> using Cxx
julia> cxx""" #include <vector> """
true
julia> cxx""" std::vector<int> a = std::vector<int> (5,6); """
true
julia> icxx""" a[0]; """
(int &) 6
julia> b = icxx""" a; """
(class std::vector<int, class std::allocator<int> >) {
}
julia> b[0]
6
julia> b
(class std::vector<int, class std::allocator<int> >) {
}
```

The above code, when entered into a Julia terminal, shows that the vector data is present. However, I'd prefer to completely transfer it into a Julia array. What is the best method of doing this?

**Note:** Eventually a shared library will be returning a `std::vector<int>`, so the question, more explicitly, is how best to convert `std::vector<int>` into a standard Julia vector. (This is referring to the variable `b` in the example code).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** The reasoning for why there is a problem doesn't seem to be clear, so hopefully the following will help (it follows on directly from the above code)

```
julia> unsafe_wrap(Array, pointer(b), length(b))
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Ptr{Int32} are not callable
julia> @cxx b;
ERROR: Could not find `b` in translation unit
julia> cxx" b; "
In file included from :1:
__cxxjl_17.cpp:1:2: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
 b; 
 ^
true
julia> icxx" b; "
ERROR: A failure occured while parsing the function body
julia> cxx" &b; "
In file included from :1:
__cxxjl_15.cpp:1:3: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
 &b; 
  ^
__cxxjl_15.cpp:1:3: error: declaration of reference variable 'b' requires an initializer
 &b; 
  ^
true
julia> icxx" &b; "
ERROR: A failure occured while parsing the function body
julia> @cxx &b;
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'b' which could not be resolved!
```

No matter how you try to pass the julia referenced variable, it cannot be parsed back into the c++ environment (and the last one broke julia completely). Nor can the same methods used to pass c++ references into julia be used. Attempting to grab the pointer of either `b`, `@b`, `b[0]` or `&b[0]` and parsing those work.

Comment: Read `test/std.jl`. `v = icxx"std::vector<int32_t>{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14};";` then `unsafe_wrap(Array, pointer(v), length(v))` *just works*.

Comment: @Isaiah Yes, this does work because the variable reference starts in the c++ space and moved to julia space. In the documentation of Cxx.j, example 8 encourages c++ variables to be directly stored as julia references (in julai space). From here it is seemingly impossible to transfer the data into a standard julia array. Your example is akin to variable `a`, whereas conversion of variable `b` is what was in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Jeff Bezanson & Isaiah for their answers (`icxx" &a[0]; "` & `sum = icxx""" std::accumulate($b.begin(), $b.end(), 0); """` respectively)

To combine everything together into a single answer I've made the following example:

```
# Converting between Julia and C++
using Cxx
cxxinclude("vector")
cxx" std::vector<int> a = std::vector<int> (5,6); "
 # Transfer variable from C++ space to julia space "as is"
b = @cxx a;

# Pass the raw data reference from the C++ variable into julia space
c = icxx" &a[0]; " # From C++ space
d = icxx" &$b[0]; " # From julia space, only difference is the '$' interpolation

# Get the number of elements in the vector
cSize = icxx" a.size(); "
dSize = icxx" $b.size(); "

# Convert to a standard julia array
juliaArray_c = unsafe_wrap(Array, c, cSize, true)
juliaArray_d = unsafe_wrap(Array, d, dSize, true).
```

Hopefully this helps others that are in the same situation.

Answer (score 6):

If copying the data is acceptable, you can call `collect` on the C++ vector to copy it to a julia vector. If you want to avoid copying, you can get the address of the data with `icxx"&a[0];"` and wrap that using `unsafe_wrap`.

Comment: I'd prefer not to copy the data if possible. The second answer (`icxx"&a[0];"`) isn't quite what I was after in the question. I'm trying to convert the variable `b`. I have tried adapting the answer using `g(x,y,z) = unsafe_wrap(Array, convert(Ptr{x}, pointer_from_objref( y ) ), z, false)` to play around with things to no avail. The addresses look correct, and individually this method works. But I cannot iterate over them. Any ideas?

Comment: Provided further details in the question.

Comment: You need to pass the result of `&a[0]` as the pointer argument to `unsafe_wrap`. If you index the vector, that pulls out an integer, and then you'll be wrapping a pointer to that integer object, which is not what you want.

Comment: Using `unsafe_wrap(Array, pointer_from_objref( &arr[0] ), 5, false)` resulted in `ERROR: unsupported or misplaced expression &`.

Comment: After a fair bit of tinkering, I've come to the conclusion that its only possible if the variable is in the "cxx space" so to speak. Which means that it is not possible to convert variable `b`, but is possible to convert `a`. I'm working on some example code which might explain more readily for others with my use case, however, I'll mark your answer as correct as for all intents and purposes it is. Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Have you tried `unsafe_wrap(Array, icxx"&a[0];", 5, false)`? The function `pointer_from_objref` gets the address of julia objects, so it is generally not what you want in these cases. `&a[0]` in c++ already returns the pointer you want; `pointer_from_objref` will give you the address of a julia object that represents that pointer. Rule of thumb is that if you already have a pointer, don't call `pointer_from_objref`.

Comment: It shows `:2:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'arr'` when using that. I'm about to post my version of things which goes from perspective a lot of people would may need after just reading the documentation (as it isn't obvious how to get around it otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

The question here is still unclear to me, but responding to the edit: to pass a `CppValue` Julia variable back in to `icxx`, use interpolation. For example:

```
julia> cxx""" std::vector<int> a = std::vector<int> (5,6); """
true

julia> b = @cxx a
(class std::__1::vector<int, class std::__1::allocator<int> >) {
}

julia> typeof(b)
Cxx.CppValue{Cxx.CxxQualType{Cxx.CppTemplate{Cxx.CppBaseType{Symbol("std::__1::vector")},Tuple{Int32,Cxx.CxxQualType{Cxx.CppTemplate{Cxx.CppBaseType{Symbol("std::__1::allocator")},Tuple{Int32}},(false, false, false)}}},(false, false, false)},24}

julia> cxxinclude("numeric")

julia> sum = icxx""" std::accumulate($b.begin(), $b.end(), 0); """
30
```

Regarding "spaces", I don't believe example 8 or the docs in general make a normative statement about variable declaration, but generally speaking, Julia references may be more convenient to use with Julia code. The given examples in Jeff's answer are the solution to make a no-copy wrapper. To work with data declared as a `std::vector`, the options I know of are: copy, wrap the pointer, or use the provided `getindex` overloads to treat the data as a (0-based) Julia array (which does the pointer-wrapping automatically, and should have no overhead).

Comment: Ah! The interpolation makes all of the difference. If you add `julia> ptr = icxx""" &$b[0]; """`, `julia> size = icxx""" $b.size(); """`, and `julia> juliaArray = unsafe_wrap(Array, ptr, size, true)` to your answer then it perfectly answers my original question. Thanks =)